# After ending compiz process Ubuntu 16.04 no longer works as expected

Tags: 16.04, compiz

As I tried to get more ram to improve performance on a game I ended the `compiz` process which consumed around 30% memory.

This somehow killed Ubuntu,or my main session since its active (compiz) on the guest session. The desktop wallpaper is all there is, I can open the "TTY", move the mouse.

Is there any way to re-open/open/restart the `compiz` process?

After a reboot it was still not working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you un-installed `compiz` you can simply reboot which will fix it anyways. Closing down a process in the process manager does not uninstall it.

However from your comments it seems you borked up the compiz settings. To fix I'd suggest renaming your current home folder and creating a new one with the following commands:

```bash
# rename/move your actual user home directory
sudo mv /home/<your username>{,.old}
# create a new home directory
sudo mkdir /home/<your username>
# take ownership of the new directory as it is currently owned
# root which is wrong
sudo chown <your username>:<your username> /home/<your username>
# make sure you still have access to the old user home directory
# the move/rename you performed earlier might have changed
# the user on that directory
sudo chown <your username>:<your username> /home/<your username>.old
# copy the essential files into the new home directory
cp /etc/skel/* /home/<your username>
```

After that it should work again, and then you can copy your data from the renamed folder over bit by bit as you need it.

Comment: Thanks :) Also, steam data isnt in the old folder, it seems to be mirroring with the new one. Shall I delete the old one to prevent it from using more memory? It wont cause any problems right?

Comment: well it only seems to mirror the new one, all your old data, desktop, downloads, etc is in the old folder, which you can delete after you got all the data from it (not the settings, this would make it mess up again).